# How to change parameters of the CA certificate from mitmproxy?

Tags: mitmproxy

Is it possible to change some parameters of the CA certificate from mitmproxy?

I intend to test my application to check if it accepts a connection using, e.g., a CA certificate with expired date or invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to generate your own CA certificates using e.g. OpenSSL, and then overwrite the mitmproxy CA ([source](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-certificates/#using-a-custom-certificate-authority)).